# Pyomo KeyError: "Error accessing indexed component: Index '('student_5', 'company_3', 'meetingtime_1')' is not valid for array component 'var_X'"

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

I have a Pyomo model that seeks to maximize the fit-score for meetings between students and companies. I use a 3-dimensional variable for student-company-meetingtime combinations. 
I am a beginner in using pyomo and I am using it with SolverStudio in Excel.
As long as I list all possible combinations in the range for model.var_X, the model is working fine. If I do not list all possible combinations, I get the following error message:

> ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for constraint company_meetingtime_capa_constraint with index ('company_3', 'meetingtime_1'):
>       KeyError: "Error accessing indexed component: Index '('student_5', 'company_3', 'meetingtime_1')' is not valid for array component 'var_X'"

I do not want to include all possible combinations, because the number is too high to handle with excel and not all combinations are feasible anyway.

Is there a way to not list all combinations and stil be able to solve it?

```
from pyomo.environ import * # For Pyomo 4.0 & later

model = AbstractModel()

## Define sets
model.idx_students = Set()
model.idx_companies = Set()
model.idx_meetingtimes = Set()
model.idx_s_c = Set(within=model.idx_students*model.idx_companies)
model.idx_s_m = Set(within=model.idx_students*model.idx_meetingtimes)
model.idx_c_m = Set(within=model.idx_companies*model.idx_meetingtimes)
model.idx_s_c_m =      
    Set(within=model.idx_students*model.idx_companies*model.idx_meetingtimes)

## Define parameters
model.prm_studentsMin = Param(model.idx_students) 
model.prm_studentsMax = Param(model.idx_students)
model.prm_company_meetingtime_capa = Param(model.idx_c_m, default=0)
model.prm_student_meetingtime = Param(model.idx_s_m, within=Binary, 
    default=0) 
model.prm_fit = Param(model.idx_s_c, default=0)
model.prm_s_c_m_locked = Param(model.idx_s_c_m, within=Binary, default=0)

## Define variables
model.var_X = Var(model.idx_s_c_m, within=Binary)

## Define objective function
def maxFit(model):
    return sum(model.var_X[n]*model.prm_fit[m]
        for (n) in model.idx_s_c_m
        for (m) in model.idx_s_c)
model.SolverResults = Objective(rule=maxFit, sense=maximize)

## Capacity for companies during meeting-times
def company_meetingtime_capa_rule(model,c,m):
    return sum(model.var_X[s,c,m] for s in model.idx_students) <=     
        model.prm_company_meetingtime_capa[c,m]
model.company_meetingtime_capa_constraint = Constraint(model.idx_c_m, rule = 
company_meetingtime_capa_rule)

## Number of meetings for students and companies
def TerminstudentscompaniesRule(model, s, c):
    return sum(model.var_X[s,c,m] for m in model.idx_meetingtimes) <= 1
model.TerminstudentscompaniesConstraint = Constraint(model.idx_s_c,     
    rule=TerminstudentscompaniesRule)

## meetingtime availability of students
def studentsmeetingtimeRule(model, s,m):
    return sum(model.var_X[s,c,m] for c in model.idx_companies) <=     
        model.prm_student_meetingtime[s,m]
model.studentsmeetingtimeConstraint = Constraint(model.idx_s_m,     
    rule=studentsmeetingtimeRule)

## locked meetings
def lockedeTermineRule(model, s,c,m):
    return (model.var_X[s,c,m]) >= model.prm_s_c_m_locked[s,c,m]
model.lockedeTermineConstraint = Constraint(model.idx_s_c_m,     
    rule=lockedeTermineRule)

## Min number of meetings for students
def minTerminestudentsRule(model,s):
    return sum(model.var_X[s,c,m] for c in model.idx_companies for m in     
        model.idx_meetingtimes) >= model.prm_studentsMin[s]
model.minTerminestudentsConstraint = Constraint(model.idx_students,     
    rule=minTerminestudentsRule)

## Max number of meeting for students
def maxTerminestudentsRule(model,s):
    return sum(model.var_X[s,c,m] for c in model.idx_companies for m in 
        model.idx_meetingtimes) <= model.prm_studentsMax[s]
model.maxTerminestudentsConstraint = Constraint(model.idx_students,     
    rule=maxTerminestudentsRule)
```

Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to just sum over the variables that do exist in the `Var` with something like:

```
model.var_X = Var(model.idx_s_c_m, within=Binary)

## Capacity for companies during meeting-times
def company_meetingtime_capa_rule(model,c,m):
    return sum(model.var_X[s,c,m] for s in model.idx_students
        if (s,c,m) in model.idx_s_c_m) \
        <= model.prm_company_meetingtime_capa[c,m]
model.company_meetingtime_capa_constraint = Constraint(
    model.idx_c_m, rule = company_meetingtime_capa_rule)
```